# TikZ: How to pass the font size of the calling document to the called standalone tikz file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, standalone

I would like to make any change in the font size of the main calling document affect the font size of the text and the drawing dimensions of the standalone file since any current change in the `article` font size has no effect on the standalone file.

The following images shows no change in the text font size of the standalone tikz drawing despite changing it in the calling document.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{pic.tex}
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em, font=\normalsize]
            \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Test} (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[mode=build, subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    fontsize = 14pt
    \includestandalone{pic}
\end{document}
```

---

### Update 1 (Compiling case (d) of @Cicada's answer)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{pic\jobname.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    \begin{document}
          \color{red}
            inside
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em]
            \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Test} (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[mode=build, subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\section*{d}
    fontsize = 14pt \includestandalone{pic\jobname}

    \huge fontsize huge \includestandalone{pic\jobname}

    \tiny fontsize tiny \includestandalone{pic\jobname}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

4 almost empty pages

[image]

https://docdro.id/4t5urCy

#### log file of main document

https://pastebin.com/ws9Fj0tA

#### log file of standalone file

https://pastebin.com/Dt7phZrU

Comment: `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [32pt]` - valid sizes are 8,10, 12, I think. You may need to use relative-size commands like `\huge`, or fontspec's `Scale=` option.

Comment: @Cicada Please, check my question update.

Comment: Is `font=\normalsize` in the include intentional?

Comment: @Cicada not essential. Just experimenting

Comment: `\begin{filecontents*}{pic\jobname.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \begin{document}
    xxTest\color{red}
        \tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Test} (2,2);
    \end{document} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[mode=build, subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    fontsize = 14pt
    \includestandalone{pic\jobname}
\huge    \includestandalone{pic\jobname}
\tiny    \includestandalone{pic\jobname}
\end{document}`

Comment: `filecontents` needs the `[overwrite]` option, if experimenting.

Comment: @Cicada Would you please write an answer based on my question code? since it seems I am missing something preventing me from getting what I want, I actually need the drawn rectangle and the text inside get resized automatically with every font size.

Comment: @Cicada The following doesn't work as expected. Word `font` should have the same size of word `Text` inside the rectangle. `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{pic.tex}
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em]
   \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Test} (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[mode=build, subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \huge font \includestandalone{pic}
\end{document}`

Comment: If you want to compile the standalone file into a PDF, then it must  have the packages that support the commands, like `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usepackage{xcolor}`. If you want to just include the standalone code, then the usepackage commands can be, if you want, called in the main file before the include. What is the purpose of compiling the standalone file Do you want to include pdfpages instead of code?

Comment: I compiled on a TexLive 2020.

Comment: @Cicada I actually need to make use of the image externalization of standalone package to have the image prebuilt to save compilation time later (of course, mode=buildnew should be used instead of mode=build) since it won't be useful to load the package to use it as a mere \inputfile.

Comment: @Cicada I managed to reproduce your answer output when not using -shell-escape but no external image has been built which is opposite to the essence of using standalone package to save the image compilation time whenever its code is not changed.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the workflow you want? I just compiled the main document, nothing else. I did not use `pdfpages` to include any external PDF.

Comment: @Cicada most probably, you compiled without using -shell-escape, which leads to not having the image of the rectangle built  externally in your folder as a standalone image. The main goal is to use standalone to externalizalize the build of images without having to compile their codes every single time.

Comment: `mode=build` uses the source code. I don't have shell escape enabled `buildmissing` or `buildnew` sound more like what you want.

Comment: But then, you want to scale the image?

Comment: @Cicada Not necessary to scale it afterwards. The important thing is to have my image built externally so I can have two advantages: save compilation time as long as its code doesn't change. The second advantage is to be able to use it as a standalone image anywhere else.

Comment: "any settings done in the main document which would affects the source code will not have an effect on the image. This can be positive or negative dependent on the case." - p26 of the manual.

Comment: @Cicada That's pretty sad. I will reward your answer but not accept it since I will be waiting for some future release of the package with this feature XD

Comment: I cannot provide an answer, so have amended the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer because the question as far as I can understand it relates to the standalone image(PDF) to be included in the main file, with the proviso that the standalone PDF be compiled only once to save compilation time.

If, instead, standalone source code is used, the standalone PDF will inherit any applicable main document settings like fontsize but the standalone PDF will be (re)compiled on each run of the main document.

---

If source code is used:

(Original answer)

Don't use `font=\normalsize` inside your tikz picture.

(a) Your question code does not load tikz at the correct time: "Environment tikzpicture undefined.", says the log. `tikz` package needs to be loaded *before* tikz commands can be used.

No illustration (a).

(b) `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em, font=\normalsize]` sets the fontsize inside the rectangle, overriding the font size used in and by the calling file at that point in the processing. The rectangle size is set to relative font size (`em`) so expands or contracts with it.

[image: text normalsize]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{pic\jobname.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em, font=\normalsize]
            \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Test} (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[mode=build, subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\section*{b}
    fontsize = 14pt \includestandalone{pic\jobname}

    \huge fontsize huge \includestandalone{pic\jobname}

    \tiny fontsize tiny \includestandalone{pic\jobname}
\end{document}
```

(c) Do `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em]` so as not to override the font size.

[image: fontsize changes]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{pic\jobname.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em]
            \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Test} (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[mode=build, subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\section*{c}
    fontsize = 14pt \includestandalone{pic\jobname}

    \huge fontsize huge \includestandalone{pic\jobname}

    \tiny fontsize tiny \includestandalone{pic\jobname}
\end{document}
```

(d) Notice that inside the included file, formatting commands (e.g., colour) are restricted to the file itself. This implies that the contents of the included file are processed in their own group (as if with `{`...`}` or equivalents).

[image: local group]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{pic\jobname.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    \begin{document}
          \color{red}
            inside
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em]
            \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Test} (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[mode=build, subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\section*{d}
    fontsize = 14pt \includestandalone{pic\jobname}

    \huge fontsize huge \includestandalone{pic\jobname}

    \tiny fontsize tiny \includestandalone{pic\jobname}
\end{document}
```

(e) Fontsize option for the documentclass works as expected.

[image: class fontsize opotion]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{pic\jobname.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    \begin{document}
          \color{red}
            inside
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em]
            \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Test} (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[mode=build, subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\section*{e}
        \fontname\font\\
    fontsize = 12pt \includestandalone{pic\jobname}

    \huge       \fontname\font\\ fontsize huge \includestandalone{pic\jobname}

    \tiny\fontname\font\\ fontsize tiny \includestandalone{pic\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I will take some time to completely understand it then get back in case of further inquiries.

Comment: Unknowingly, none of your MWEs worked as expected for me and I get an error indicating that `\usetikzlibrary` is undefined. For instance, the log file of your case `(d)` can be found here https://pastebin.com/as6uxQWm.

Comment: @Diaa, in standalone file is not loaded `tikz` package. try to ad `tikz` as option to `standalone` document class: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`

Comment: @Zarko The output will be worse than what I posted in my question.

Comment: @Diaa, to be honest, I didn't check how your question nor answer. So my conclusion after only look code in answer was wrong. On my PC answer works without errors, however it also work if I add `tikz` package as I mentioned. I test with today upgraded MikTeX (20.12).

Comment: @Zarko I just updated miktex, and this document https://pastebin.com/JkhkMaCQ has this weird output https://docdro.id/mAr4GXy. This is the log of main file https://pastebin.com/g6ukLBxZ and this is the log of the standalone file https://pastebin.com/FcpaDeUB.

Comment: @Dia, I do not know, what result you expected. Frankly said, I do not understood you problem well.

Comment: @Zarko I need the change in font size of the main/calling document reflects the drawing size and text font of the standalone file. The output of this answer is I what I need, but I can't reproduce it even with up-to-date tex distribution.

Comment: I don't know background of your document. When I write some document, I store settings for main document into private `.sty` file and then load it in main file as wel in `standalone` files.

Comment: @Zarko So, if you just copied and pasted this answer of Cicada, it works and gives the same output?

Comment: @Diaa All the MWEs from the answer of Cicada work when they are just copied and pasted

Comment: @JuCa Please, check my question update.

Comment: @Cicada Would you please give your thoughts on my question update?

Comment: I get the output from the screenshots only without `--shell-escape`, or if I remove the `mode=build,` from the options.